# How do I specify Azure Storage Lifecycle Management for specific containers?

Tags: azure

I have a storage account that has multiple containers. I would like to set a rule for only one specific container (let's call it container1), but the documentation in Microsoft doesn't seem to specify this scenario.

I tried to set a rule with prefix match to the container in question, but so far the rule doesn't seem to apply to any object in the container. This is how the rule looks like now:

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "name": "move-to-cool",
      "type": "Lifecycle",
      "definition": {
        "actions": {
          "baseBlob": {
            "tierToCool": {
              "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 30
            }
          }
        },
        "filters": {
          "blobTypes": [
            "blockBlob"
          ],
          "prefixMatch": [
            "container1/"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a delay in when the rule will be in effect? Please help me out

Comment: It can take up to 24 hours till the first run. The lifecycle runs on a 24h cycle so the blobs are only checked once per day. The prefix match looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

- Thanks  `@NotFound` for the comment.
- We can set the rules even from the azure portal follow the below steps.
- Open the Storage account
- Under `Data Management` select `Lifecycle management`
  and click on `Add rule` as shown below.

[image]

- Give the `Rule name`, select `limit blob with filters` under `Block type` and select the required `blob type` and `Blob Subtype`.
  [image]
- Select `Move to cool storage` => `Next`

[image]

- Select the `container path` => `Add`

[image]

- As mentioned by `@NotFound` wait for few hours to get the changes reflected.